# how to get access without a user

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api, token

I am trying to follow this [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) to get access token. I am getting access token using API request **https://login.microsoftonline.com/<-tenant-id->/oauth2/token**. When i used step 5 for above given link i got the following error :

```
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
"message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "e9e9820e-2a3f-411a-bc77-760c9369fc8f",
  "date": "2020-01-02T06:17:41"
}
}
}
```

I have registered app with the following permission : Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite, Sites.Read.All, User.Read, User.Read.All and have generated secret key and registered redirect url as : 
User.Read.All.

My questions are:
 1. Have i done anything wrong while creating app?
 2. Why step 4 is not working of the link?
 3. Did i get wrong access access using the above given api request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In step 5, it calls the Microsoft Graph - [`Get a user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), so make sure your app has the `User.Read.All` Application permission in Microsoft Graph(must be `application` permission, not `delegated` permission), after adding the permission, it appears like below(**Note**: don't forget to click the Grant admin consent button)

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the doc you provided, it uses the v2.0 endpoint `/oauth2/v2.0/token`, but you use the v1.0 endpoint `/oauth2/token` in your question.

So please change the request URL to `/oauth2/v2.0/token`, then use the one below.

Request URL:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Request body:

```
client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

You can get the token in the [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

[image]

Then use the token to call the [`Get a user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<object-id of the user>
```

[image]